# Am I pure or not?

Tags: fiqh, taharah, ghusl

After urinating and doing istinja I felt something come out I checked and saw that it was a white liquid similar to water however sometimes I get white urine so I don’t know if this is urine or water. I touched it with my hand and then wiped the wetness with a towel and after I checked once again and then I touched many things in the house. Am I pure and are the things I touched pure?

Comment: Winter Bucky I am confused by your answer. Are you saying the things I touched are pure and I’m pure or not. The fluid which came didn’t have a smell and was white I could see it on the tip. I touched the fluid with my hand and then wiped it with a towel but didn’t wash my hands and then touched many things. I even slept in those clothes.

Comment: It meant here is that if there is no combination present of odor or taste or colour, then it is considered as clean/pure. However, if you are unsure of this, you can always wash the part with water, and consider it as clean.

Answer (score -1):

Urine, animal faeces and blood belong to the *Mutawassitoh* *najis* category. In this *Mutawassitoh* *najis* category, Habib Hasan bin Ahmad al-Kaff stated that the *najis* is divided into two categories namely **hukmiyyah** (*حكمية*) and '**ainiyyah** (*عينية*).

The **Hukmiyyah** is the one that does not appear clearly as there are no signs like odor, taste and color. The only way to clean it is to simply pour water into the area where it is contaminated. Whereas' **ainiyyah** is a *najis* that can be seen and has properties like either odor or taste or color. The way to clean it is with water until all of its properties (odor, taste and color) are gone. If the *najis* properties can be removed with just one wash, then it is enough. On the other hand if the *najis* is not able to be removed in one wash, then it needs to be washed second and third times.

In other words, if the *najis* cannot be removed with one wash, then it is necessary to wash it a second time. And if it is not yet lost, it is necessary to wash it a third time. If the *najis* has not yet been cleared of its properties by three times washing with aids such as soap and so on, then this is consider as a difficult situation (حالة التعسر). - see  **al-Taqrirat al-Sadidah, page 135**

Sheikh al-Islam Zakaria al-Ansari mentioned that examples of hukmiyyah impurities are like dried urine and cannot be seen in its effects or properties. So, the way to clean it is to simply pour water on it once. As for the 'ainiyyah, it is necessary to eliminate its properties of odor, taste and color, unless there is a difficulty in eliminating one of the two properties, either color or odor. Therefore, in this case it is not necessary to eliminate it, and is considered as clean. However, if both properties are presented together (odor and color) on the surface, then it is necessary that both of these qualities be eliminated as there is a strong evidence that the *najis* is still presented. **(See Fath al-Wahhab, 1/25 and Kasiifah al-Sahara, p. 182-184)**

Wallahualam.

Comment: I don't see how this actually answers the question at all. See [answer].